# Map models in the loop

Tags: c#, orm, mapping, automapper

I need to map two models when names are equal. I grab them via reflection like this:

```
var domainModels = Assembly.Load("Domain.Model").GetTypes();
var dtoModels = Assembly.Load("Service.Model").GetTypes();
```

I've tried to do this in the nested loop like this:

```
foreach (var dto in dtoModels)
        {

            foreach (var domain in domainModels)
            {
                if (domain.Name == dto.name)
                {
                     Mapper.CreateMap<domainModels.First(), dtoModels.First()>()

                }                            
            }
```

but I got an error:     Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'Type' I now that I need to have a class inside <>. How to achieve that? Is there better way to mapp two models whene the names match?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the overload of CreateMap that allows you to pass the types as parameters:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap(domainModels.First(), dtoModels.First());
```